# This thing all things devour

Tags: riddle

Here is a riddle from the Hobbit.

> This thing all things devours;
>
> Birds, beasts, trees, flowers;
>
> Gnaws iron, bites steel;
>
> Grinds hard stones to meal;
>
> Slays king, ruins town,
>
> And beats high mountain down.

What am I talking about?

Comment: I am just curious, but why are there many down-votes?

Comment: You are probably being down-voted because this riddle is fairly well known, and you even said exactly where the riddle is from.  Also, you didn't say anything prohibiting using the internet.  That's what I would guess, though I just saw this riddle.

Comment: This is from Smeagol

Comment: A really angry invincible monster with an eating disorder! I think i got it.

Comment: @AJL why does he need to explicitly say *dont cheat*?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I swear @HughMeyers posted this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **TIME**

***This thing all things devour;
Birds, beasts, trees, flowers;***

> All the things consume TIME - birds, beasts, trees , flowers
>  everything devour **TIME** they age by time, never the same.

***Gnaws iron, bites steel;
Grinds hard stones to meal;***

> Once the Mining (referring the dwarfs mine place) place that could
>  earn and keep itself busy would stop one day - **TIME can change
>  anything**.

***Slays king, ruins town,
And beats high mountain down.***

> the kings and towns which are once wealthy will have to be abandoned
>  and they are destroyed not even mountains are left  over time they
>  have to change - **TIME matters Most**.
>   No matter what comes on its way , it will never stop, everybody has
>  to surrender under one that is **"TIME"**.